# Eclipse v4.17 incompatible jvm - revert to v4.16

Tags: java, eclipse, version, eclipse-2020-06, eclipse-2020-09

I had eclipse 4.16 and downloaded update to 4.17. This version of Eclipse is however incompatible with java 1.8. Can i go back/ revert to to version 4.16? I read some questions but i didnt find answer I could apply

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "incompatible with Java 1.8"?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Eclipse 2020-09 requires at least Java 11 to run

Comment: @greg-449 I'm wanting to get OP's explanation. It's entirely possible that a satisfactory resolution is adding an installed JDK for Java 8.

Comment: what @greg-449 wrote. But i need work with java 1.8

Comment: Eclipse itself must run with Java >= 11 but the projects you're working on can be on Java 1.8

Comment: @Guillaume I'm experiencing a similar problem. Even after setting Java 1.8 as my project's JDK, it seems Eclipse Java builder is still using its own JDK to build it. I'm facing an NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement in some of my  mappers (with mapstruct annotation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need change eclipse.ini because when you run new version of eclipse it will prompt you that you have incopatible version of java. For me version 1.8 did a trick and save
   [eclipse.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFCX0.png)
2. Run eclipse. It should run but you will probably wont see your workspace. Go Help -> About
   [eclipse without worspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v73Oe.png)
3. In About window click Installation Details
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO1Aa.png)
4. There click Installation History tab and find your preferable version and click revert
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35uDq.png)
5. After a while it finish and probably prompt you Security Warning. Click install anyway if you know what you installing is secure
   [security warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ1cd.png)
6. Profit. You can run your eclipse again

Comment: Thank you! Changing eclipse.ini to use java 1.8 allowed me to start Eclipse, and though everything was "broken", I could access the menu (Help » About) and find the option to revert. You saved the day ☺